# Is cellular for Apple Watch ever available for a pre-paid phone plan?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, cellular-data

At least in Australia, all the cellular providers only provide cellular support for the Apple Watch if the iPhone is also on a post-paid plan, with no support for pre-paid plans.

Is this the same internationally? Is there any instance of cellular support for the Apple Watch enabled with a pre-paid phone plan?

I wonder if this is a contractual restraint, rather than a technical constraint.

Comment: Can't you just get a pre-paid SIM and use it with Apple Watch? In India, no pre-paid provider asks you what device you are going to use it on. This does seem ridiculous and a sorry state of affair for all you Aussies!

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical constraint preventing an Apple Watch cellular from being used with a pre-paid plan.

I have used an Apple Watch Cellular with pre-paid plan in India.

Comment: Does it work for Airtel prepaid sim ? @Nimesh

Comment: @Praveen Carries supporting Apple Watch cellular can be found here: https://www.apple.com/in/watch/cellular/

Comment: This is for those who are looking for answer.
I checked, only jio supports apple watch with cellular on prepaid at this time. 
Postpaid is supported by all three airtel, vi and jio.